# @ModelAttribute values don't correlated with values submitted in HTML Form

Tags: java, html, spring

My form backing object (`@ModelAttribute`) contains a List of persons, and I access to them using indexed properties, like this: `persons[0].name`.

On UI side user have ability to delete some person - so technically I remove the parent `<div>` element which contain all form elements related to person with some index.

But the problem is that when submitting form the `@ModelAttribute`'s List still contains removed objects, although they are not present when HTML Form is submitted (I can see it using Chrome Dev Tools).

Where can be problem? Why `@ModelAttribute`s List still contain items which was removed and not submitted to server?

Comment: Could you please update your question with the relevant parts of your controller and form?

Comment: Is this `ModelAttribute` designated as a `SessionAttribute`?